# Can the word "information" be used with both singular and plural nouns?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

Here is the sentence I'm constructing:

"To begin, you'll need your school ID, username, and password; if you don't already have this information, your school can provide you with them."

My problem is that it looks like I'm mixing singular and plural here; "them" in this context is referring back to the ID, username, and password, whereas "this information" sounds like a singular object.

I know that "information" is considered a non-count word in English which means it can be used as both plural and singular without changing its form, but in this sentence the result ends up sounding weird.

Can I get some input on how I should revise the sentence?

Comment: Do not revise the sentence. It is correct.

Comment: *Information* is singular, so the correct pronoun is *it*.

Comment: Non-counts nouns like "information" are usually invariably singular, not 'both plural and singular' as you stated.

Comment: Perhaps I phrased it incorrectly, my apologies. What I meant was, in the context of the two sentences together, it is obvious that "this information" refers to multiple items even if in the context of just the second sentence it is treated as a singular item. This is what is really throwing me off; the singular 'this information' refers to a multitude of items as an umbrella term of sorts, so I'm unsure if I should use "it" or "them". My preferred outcome would still end the sentence with "them", but I'm not sure how I would revise "this information" to accomodate.

Comment: You can usually pick out a modifier which makes the uncountable noun countable, e.g. *those pieces of information*.  Because *this* refers to it in a singular state, the pronoun *them* becomes ambiguous in that context. You may want to refer to the information using *it*, instead of *them*.

Comment: You could just skip over that word altogether:  _To begin, you'll need your school ID, username, and password; if you don't already have these, your school can provide you with them._

Comment: An alternate to Adam's version is *if you don't already have these pieces of information, your school...*

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence, grammatically speaking, is fine.  However, as Peter Shor said, the pronoun *it* might be better suited to your sentence:

*To begin, you'll need your school ID, username, and password; if you don't already have this information, your school can provide you with it.*

I would also recommend Adam's way; generally, the phrase *less is more* applies when revising writing.  (To a reasonable extent, of course.)   Another way to phrase this sentence is with a dependent clause:

*To begin, you'll need your school ID, username, and password, which can be provided by your school.*

Here, I omitted the phrase *if you don't have it/them*, as I don't feel that it is necessary.  However, you could also do:

*To begin, you'll need your school ID, username, and password, which can be provided by your school, in the event that you don't have them.*

But I find that to be more verbose without providing meaning.